# Trying to move the old log files from one folder to another

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to move the older log files (older than 7 days) from the source to the target folder using the below script:

But this code doesn't move the file. Where as when I use the below code for deleting the older files (older than 7 days) it works!

I tried saving them as .ps1 file and .bat file, but no luck in moving. Can someone please help me figure out the issue?

Comment: Is there any output from the first command? If so, please copy and paste it in text mode into the question. Why is there a backslash -before- the `E:`?

Comment: Use `robocopy`.

Comment: What about the backslash in front of the destination path and the `$` trailing `tm1servers` ? To debug, put an echo in front of the move command.

Comment: @LotPings and@lit I tried removing the backslash and '$' it worked thanks. But When I try to have the destination folder as a share point, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried mapping with the IP address it worked!
and I use `-get childitem` for moving.

**Note: That ID address posted is just a random number I came up with. Also there was no `-credential` needed in my case**

Answer (score 1):

This will help for you..

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\SC\A" | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(7)} | Move -Destination "E:\SC\B"
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not work the same way. You need to create a PSDrive.

```
New-PSDrive -Name atemp -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $cred -Root "$spdir"
Copy-Item -Path "$logfilename" -Destination "$spdir"
Remove-PSDrive atemp
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting 'PSDrive', will work on that let you know the results.

Comment: What is the `NET USE` command you would use to successfully map the drive letter?

Comment: Open Windows Explorer (file browser). Put `\\abbvienet.com\app\Enterprise\Cognos\VI-ONE_Dev\Backups\TM1 10.2\wa01095d\HQ_PS_Performance\logs` into the address bar. What is the result?

Comment: I'm able to access the link via windows explorer, opens the folder 'logs'